# How to prevent the Win8 explorer navigation panel from automatically expanding? (I have disabled auto expansion in folder options)

Tags: windows-8

The left-hand navigation panel in Windows 8 keeps expanding automatically based on my folder browsing. This requires me to constantly manually adjust it back to the default position when I want to access my libraries, download folder, etc. How can I make the menu remain in the default position?

I have already checked that "Automatically expand current folder" under "Folder options" is disabled.

This is what my explorer looks like now:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xiaV.png]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYX18.png]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this? I have the same issue in both Windows 8 and 8.1. So annoying.